# List tool not available in Visual Studio C# 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am following a video [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QmgmGIn0mZY) and at 3:22 it uses list tool which contains tablix property.

But I couldn't find this tool in VS2022. Upon searching the tools I got other lists options like ListBox and ListView but not the exact one!

Comment: It's part of the SSRS reports

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio2022

Comment: Hi, if my answer is helpful to you, you can mark it so that it can help more people.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you do not have [Microsoft RDLC Report Designer 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio2022) installed.

Microsoft SQL Reporting Services RDLC Designer for Windows Forms and Asp.Net.

Package contains New Projects and Report Designer for VB and C#.

This package works in conjunction with the Report Viewer Nuget Package. The Windows Forms projects have a reference to existing package and require rebuild or download to function properly.